# Android studio imageView (phone) is not showing

Tags: android-studio

I installed android studio and for some reason the image of the mobile phone does not appear.Is something missing? Anyone have some tips to solve the problem? I will send two pictures to facilitate understanding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - and do not add screenshots of the code. Copy-paste it into the question

Comment: @Zoe it's an IDE usage question, should be tagged with Android Studio and maybe Android tag is not needed.

Comment: This normally happens when you have low configuration system. This happens GUI do not get rendered. Just click Desin and Text tab 2 or 3 times. It will start rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to toggle the required Design and Blueprint mode from the Design tab of your layout editor in Android Studio. Follow as shown in screenshots below:

[image: Design Tab view toggle button]

[image: Toggle view type from drop down menu]